# Break doesn't work in try with resources, but work in try without resources

Tags: java, try-catch, try-with-resources

Break doesn't work in try with resources, but work in try ***without*** resources!
This is a simple example for this situation. I caught this "bug" in work project.
When I use try without resources

```
try {
Resources resources = getResources()
// some code here, look below
}
```

I have only one iteration of my cycle, and it's right because I have the condition "if true then break", but when I changed try without recourse on try WITH resources.

```
try (Resources resources = getResources()) {
    // some code here, look below
}
```

I was shocked! The cycle became endless! Why?

Full code:

```
public class Test {
            public static void testTryWithResAndBreak() {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("we are in (while(true))");
                    try (Resources resources = getResources()) {
                        System.out.println("We are in try block");
                        if (true) {
                            System.out.println("We are in the if(true) now! Next step is break");
                            break;
                        }
                        System.out.println("OOOOO___OOOO WE ARE HERE!!!");
                        resources.writeSomething();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Catched exception");
                    }
                }
            }
            private static class Resources implements AutoCloseable {
                @Override
                public void close() throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("Resources closed");
                    throw new Exception("Exception after closed resources!");
                }

                public void writeSomething() {
                    System.out.println("i wrote something");
                }
            }

            private static Resources getResources() {
                return new Resources();
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                testTryWithResAndBreak();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `if (true) {...}` may be removed by the compiler. Do you have an actual condition there?

Comment: Show the other version, something tells me you do not call close there.

Comment: @pablochan why? break didn't work? if compiler deleted my condition it didn't delete "break". For example if (true) { "do something" } will be optimize, it will become just "do something".

Comment: @JornVernee I think this does not change the problem. When i use try with resources "break" doesn't work. When i use try !without! resources "break" work correctly. Just copy my code and run, and you will see it.

Comment: I can see it already, and I can see why it does not work. I'd need to see the other version to tell you the difference.

Comment: @JornVernee 1 minutes

Comment: @JornVernee http://pastebin.com/zJfLBBp9 example with "try with resources", and this http://pastebin.com/86HQhwJw example without resources. :)

Answer (score 1):

The cycle is endless because your close is occurring at the end of the try scope. This throws an exception, which interrupts the break operation. The exception handler (which is INSIDE the while loop) then catches it, and continues to the end of the loop, and since the loop condition is 'true', continues forever. When you don't use try-with-resource, the close is never called, so the exception isn't thrown, and the break is not interrupted.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zJfLBBp9 example with "try with resources", and this http://pastebin.com/4bS5Vatr  example without resources. :)
In first example break works, but in second example doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Just before the `break` is executed, the `close` method on the `Resource` is called. This can be seen in the byte code:

```
   L9 // Print statement
    LINENUMBER 14 L9
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    LDC "We are in the if(true) now! Next step is break"
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1 // Close method call
    LINENUMBER 17 L1
    ALOAD 2
    IFNULL L10
    ALOAD 2
    INVOKEVIRTUAL Main$Resources.close ()V
   L3 // Then the break
    LINENUMBER 15 L3
    GOTO L10
```

But this `close` method throws an exception itself, which transfers control over to the `catch` block. After the `catch` block is done, the `while` loop continues its next iteration. So the `break` statement will never be executed.

The structure generated by the try-with-resources looks something like this:

```
try {
    Resources resources = null;
    try {
        resources = getResources();
        if (true) {
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {            
    } finally {
        if(resources != null)
            resources.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

This is different from your version, where the inner `finally` block already handles the exception, after which the `break` is executed. But in the above, the exception is handled by the outer `catch` block, after which control is returned to the `while` loop.

Comment: when i changed catch like this http://pastebin.com/4bS5Vatr , i have endless cycle too

Comment: can u describe me, why?

Comment: "But this close method throws an exception itself, which transfers control over to the catch block. " but close() method must execute after try block, isn't it? And the "break" in the try block.

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov You have endless cycles too, because it works the same way as try-with-resources. Regarding your last comment, as you can see in the byte code, the `close` method is called _just_ before exiting the try block, not after it.

Comment: @JornVarnee i can't understand, why close() called just before than break. How we can close resources if i have " resources.writeSomething()" in the last line in try?

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov That will still compile, but it's actually unreachable code, it will never be executed. Either there is an exception, or the loop breaks.

Comment: @JornVarneeif (true) break - is it unreachable code? Are you serious? Can you write full description, please...

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov Sorry, I thought my answer explained it adequately. The lines `System.out.println("OOOOO___OOOO WE ARE HERE!!!");` and `resources.writeSomething();` are both unreachable code. The `if` statement will never return control to the `try` block, since the condition is `true`, it will always execute, and either throw an exception or break the loop.