# Flow Control in try-with-resources close exception

Tags: java, try-with-resources

I couldn't find the answer with a Google search, so I ask it here (for navigation help).
If one were to return a value in a try-with-resources block, the close method throws an exception, I handle the exception without throwing, and resume execution, is the value I tried to return returned, or does execution resume after the catch block? For example:

```
public static int test(){
    class Foo implements AutoCloseable{
        @Override
        public void close(){
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
    try(Foo foo = new Foo()){
        return 1;
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e){
        //handle exception without throwing
    }
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a mark duplicate link thing... I was going to link it to https://stackoverflow.com/q/39777022/1366594

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Break doesn't work in try with resources, but work in try without resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777022/break-doesnt-work-in-try-with-resources-but-work-in-try-without-resources)

Comment: Giving a sample code could make things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception throwing causes the execution to reach the `catch` statement and so `2` is returned.
It is related to the `close()` operation that is necessarily invoked in a  `try-with-resources` statement before allowing the method to return.

I didn't find a specific part of the JLS that specifies a case with the return.
So you have to consider that the general explanation is applicable :

> [14.20.3. try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3)
>
> ...
>
> If all resources initialize successfully, the try block executes as
>   normal and then all non-null resources of the try-with-resources
>   statement are closed.

Note that without `try-with-resources`, you would probably write this code :

```
try(Foo foo = new Foo()){
    return 1;
}
catch (RuntimeException e){
    //handle exception without throwing
}
return 2;
```

in this way :

```
try{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.close(); // handled automatically by  try-with-resources 
    return 1;
}       
catch (RuntimeException e){
    //handle exception without throwing
}
return 2;
```

So it should make sense why `1` cannot be returned.
Note that the code generated by the compiler by a `try-with-resources` is much  longer and more complex than the pseudo equivalence I provided because of  suppressed exceptions.  But it is not your question, so let me favor this view.